# Plotting graphs with pandas - Splitting graph into separate monthly graphs

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I've been getting into this whole data management stuff with Pandas and I'm now trying to plot out my results. My code is kind of messy and my variable names seem like nonsense (bad coding etiquette, sorry) but I've been trying a bunch of different methods and I'm a little stuck. Here is what I have:

```
    Output from xxP.columns:
Index(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct',
       'Nov', 'Dec'],
      dtype='object')
```

---

```
Output from xxP.head:
<bound method NDFrame.head of         Jan    Feb   Mar   Apr    May  ...    Aug    Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
Year                                   ...                                
2010    0.0    4.8  27.8  30.6   89.8  ...   76.1   33.6  20.6  10.8   9.5
2011   21.6    0.0   0.2  21.7   85.0  ...   96.6   89.9  35.4  24.2  51.8
2012   35.2   14.6   0.0  57.0   92.0  ...   94.2   70.4  12.8  46.8  59.0
2013   10.3    2.8  53.2  29.8  135.0  ...  127.3  145.2  34.8   7.8   1.0
2014    0.4    0.0  13.2  17.8  123.0  ...   67.2   66.8  41.3  20.7   0.2
2015    3.2   15.8  20.3  44.1   66.3  ...  106.6   45.5  24.6  42.7  15.0
2016   21.0   12.8  14.3  55.3  121.8  ...  143.0   91.2  32.9  28.0  11.0
2017    5.8  115.3  25.8   0.0   66.1  ...  169.2   79.7  23.5  24.3  28.8
2018  124.4    0.3   5.6  31.9   57.9  ...  150.4   26.9  44.4   5.1   3.0
2019    4.6    0.8  12.0  31.9   25.2  ...  113.6   34.7  32.8  13.3   2.3
2020    2.1   11.0  40.9  11.1  107.3  ...    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

[11 rows x 12 columns]>
```

I'm trying to plot my data so I can see and compare each year. When running a simple xxP.plot(y='Rain','kind='bar') I get the following:

[image: Graph output]

The formatting is great and the values are appropriate, but is there a way to separate these out according to the month? This would result in 12 separate graphs, one for each month, with the year along the x axis. I have used the groupby function when plotting before but I'm unsure of how to do it in this situation which is why I included the xxP.columns output.

Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer in the chance that you want subplots instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Plot each month to a separate graph by iterating through the monthly columns

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
data = {'Year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
        'Jan': [0.0, 21.6, 35.2, 10.3, 0.4, 3.2, 21.0, 5.8, 124.4, 4.6, 2.1],
        'Feb': [4.8, 0.0, 14.6, 2.8, 0.0, 15.8, 12.8, 115.3, 0.3, 0.8, 11.0],
        'Mar': [27.8, 0.2, 0.0, 53.2, 13.2, 20.3, 14.3, 25.8, 5.6, 12.0, 40.9],
        'Apr': [30.6, 21.7, 57.0, 29.8, 17.8, 44.1, 55.3, 0.0, 31.9, 31.9, 11.1],
        'May': [89.8, 85.0, 92.0, 135.0, 123.0, 66.3, 121.8, 66.1, 57.9, 25.2, 107.3],
        'Aug': [76.1, 96.6, 94.2, 127.3, 67.2, 106.6, 143.0, 169.2, 150.4, 113.6, nan],
        'Sep': [33.6, 89.9, 70.4, 145.2, 66.8, 45.5, 91.2, 79.7, 26.9, 34.7, nan],
        'Oct': [20.6, 35.4, 12.8, 34.8, 41.3, 24.6, 32.9, 23.5, 44.4, 32.8, nan],
        'Nov': [10.8, 24.2, 46.8, 7.8, 20.7, 42.7, 28.0, 24.3, 5.1, 13.3, nan],
        'Dec': [9.5, 51.8, 59.0, 1.0, 0.2, 15.0, 11.0, 28.8, 3.0, 2.3, nan]}

# setup dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display
    Year    Jan    Feb   Mar   Apr    May    Aug    Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
0   2010    0.0    4.8  27.8  30.6   89.8   76.1   33.6  20.6  10.8   9.5
1   2011   21.6    0.0   0.2  21.7   85.0   96.6   89.9  35.4  24.2  51.8
2   2012   35.2   14.6   0.0  57.0   92.0   94.2   70.4  12.8  46.8  59.0
3   2013   10.3    2.8  53.2  29.8  135.0  127.3  145.2  34.8   7.8   1.0
4   2014    0.4    0.0  13.2  17.8  123.0   67.2   66.8  41.3  20.7   0.2
5   2015    3.2   15.8  20.3  44.1   66.3  106.6   45.5  24.6  42.7  15.0
6   2016   21.0   12.8  14.3  55.3  121.8  143.0   91.2  32.9  28.0  11.0
7   2017    5.8  115.3  25.8   0.0   66.1  169.2   79.7  23.5  24.3  28.8
8   2018  124.4    0.3   5.6  31.9   57.9  150.4   26.9  44.4   5.1   3.0
9   2019    4.6    0.8  12.0  31.9   25.2  113.6   34.7  32.8  13.3   2.3
10  2020    2.1   11.0  40.9  11.1  107.3    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

# plot each month
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    plt.figure()
    plt.bar(x='Year', height=col, data=df)
    plt.title(col)
    plt.show()
```

### if you want subplots instead

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns[1:], 1):
    plt.subplot(4, 3, i)
    plt.bar(x='Year', height=col, data=df)
    plt.ylim(0, df.iloc[:, 1:].max().max())
    plt.title(col)
    plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]